# Find the biggest value, the smallest value and middle value if 3 values cannot be distinct value

Tags: python, function, if-statement

Here is my code snippet regarding finding the biggest value, the smallest value and the middle value if all these 3 values can be distinct value. What if some of them can be same value , How can I find the biggest value, the smallest value and the middle?

```
num1 = int(input("Enter 1. number : "))
num2 = int(input("Enter 2. number : "))
num3 = int(input("Enter 3. number : "))

print("Numbers\n1.number : {}\n2.number : {}\n3.number : {}".format(num1, num2, num3))

def thebiggest(num1, num2, num3):
    if (num1 >= num2) and (num1 >= num3):
        largest_num = num1
    elif (num2 >= num1) and (num2 >= num3):
        largest_num = num2
    else:
        largest_num = num3

    print("The largest number : ", largest_num)

def thesmallest(num1, num2, num3):
    if (num1 <= num2) and (num1 <= num3):
        smallest_num = num1
    elif (num2 <= num1) and (num2 <= num3):
        smallest_num = num2
    else:
        smallest_num = num3
    print("The smallest value : ", smallest_num)


def middle(num1, num2, num3):
    if (num1 <= num2 and num2 <= num3):
        middle_value = num2
    elif (num2 <= num1 and num1<= num3):
        middle_value = num3
    else:    
        middle_value = num1

    print("Middle value : ", middle_value)


thebiggest(num1, num2, num3)
thesmallest(num1, num2, num3)
middle(num1, num2, num3)
```

Comment: put into array, sort that and return them in sorted order?

Comment: If they're the same value, then the smallest/middle/largest number is either, you're printing the value, not the variable

Comment: @Sayse Can you tell me which way I should use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll benefit greatly from putting the numbers in a list. In this particular case, you have 3 values only, and you can store a variable for each of those, but imagine having hundreds of numbers.

If put in an array, you can use built-in methods to solve this task easily, i.e. ,`max(list)` or `min(list)`. I guess there isn't a built-in method to find the median value, so you can simply order the list and get the value at index `1`.

You may also use the f-strings to make the code more compact and clean.

Here is a possible way to write your code:

```
nums = []

for i in range(3):
    nums.append(int(input(f"Enter {i+1}. number : ")))

print(f"Numbers\n1.number : {nums[0]}\n2.number : {nums[1]}\n3.number : {nums[2]}")

sorted_nums = sorted(nums)

print (f"The largest number : {sorted_nums[2]}")
print (f"The smallest value : {sorted_nums[0]}")
print (f"Middle value : {sorted_nums[1]}")
```